# How can I force a new line after a subsection?

Tags: line-breaking

I have this code:

```
\subsection{Definitions}

\subsection{Two important results}

\textbf{Proposition}. Let $(\mathbb R^{n},d)$ be a metric space and suppose $X,Y\subset \mathbb R^{n}$ are compact subsets. Then $X\cup Y$ is compact.
```

What I want to get is a newline after the subsection. I have tried adding `\\` and it doesn't work. Also, it doesn't seem to recognize `\newline`.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your document, the word **Proposition** is printed directly after *Two important results*? This is not the default, maybe it is the documentclass setting this up or a LaTeX package. Can you show us a minimal working example?

Comment: try adding `\leavevmode` after the `\subsection`.  but really, a proposition is a theorem-like object, and would better be treated as such.

Answer (score 26):

Add the following code;

```
\hfill\\
```

after the `\subsection{...}` command. The `\hfill` fills the line with empty space, so that `\\` can end this line without an error.

Comment: Thanks, answered my question as well

Answer (score 6):

More for the Johannes_B's  comment(*) than for your question, I guess(*) that you're using the document class `amsart` or a similar document class. If(*) this is true, then the comment of  barbara point in the right direction:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{prop*}{\propositionname}
\providecommand{\propositionname}{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\section{Some section}
\subsection{Definitions}
    Some text in the same line.
\subsection{Two important results}
\begin{prop*}
   Let $(\mathbb{R}^{n},d)$ be a metric space 
   and suppose $X,Y\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are
   compact subsets. Then $X\cup Y$ is compact.
\end{prop*}
\end{document}
```

(*) This is why we always *need* a  [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't think you need `\protect`.

Comment: @egreg, Yeah, I thinked that some format of the  `\propositionname`  like  `\(Proposition\)` could be fragile but as usual you are right.

Answer (score 1):

How about inserting something like

```
\vskip\baselineskip
```

in front of `\textbf{Proposition}`?